# BigQuery - Omit record with minimum value

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to remove the record that has the minimum value in a field. Below is a sample of my data:

```
ID       EVENT            CREATED_TIME  
1        login_event      2017-03-13 13:44:21 UTC    
2        login_event      2017-03-13 13:45:46 UTC    
3        login_event      2017-03-16 15:08:24 UTC    
4        login_event      2017-04-21 20:08:44 UTC    
5        login_event      2017-03-16 15:08:59 UTC    
6        login_event      2017-04-21 20:09:25 UTC    
7        login_event      2017-04-21 20:11:46 UTC
```

I would like to run a query and remove the record with the earliest CREATED_TIME. Below is desired output:

```
ID       EVENT            CREATED_TIME  
2        login_event      2017-03-13 13:45:46 UTC    
3        login_event      2017-03-16 15:08:24 UTC    
4        login_event      2017-04-21 20:08:44 UTC    
5        login_event      2017-03-16 15:08:59 UTC    
6        login_event      2017-04-21 20:09:25 UTC    
7        login_event      2017-04-21 20:11:46 UTC
```

I have found the OMIT RECORD IF clause in the BigQuery documentation, but I couldn't really get it working. I know I can do this using the combination of RANK, PARTITION, and WHERE rank != 1. However, I feel like there should be a more intuitive way to do achieve this objective (e.g. via OMIT RECORD IF).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(start) 
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    CREATED_TIME = MIN(CREATED_TIME) OVER(PARTITION BY EVENT) AS start
  FROM yourTable
)
WHERE NOT start
-- ORDER BY CREATED_TIME
```

you can try/test it with below dummy data from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'login_event' AS EVENT, TIMESTAMP '2017-03-13 13:44:21 UTC' AS CREATED_TIME UNION ALL    
  SELECT 2, 'login_event', TIMESTAMP '2017-03-13 13:45:46 UTC' UNION ALL    
  SELECT 3, 'login_event', TIMESTAMP '2017-03-16 15:08:24 UTC' UNION ALL    
  SELECT 4, 'login_event', TIMESTAMP '2017-04-21 20:08:44 UTC' UNION ALL    
  SELECT 5, 'login_event', TIMESTAMP '2017-03-16 15:08:59 UTC' UNION ALL    
  SELECT 6, 'login_event', TIMESTAMP '2017-04-21 20:09:25 UTC' UNION ALL    
  SELECT 7, 'login_event', TIMESTAMP '2017-04-21 20:11:46 UTC' 
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(start) 
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    CREATED_TIME = MIN(CREATED_TIME) OVER(PARTITION BY EVENT) AS start
  FROM yourTable
)
WHERE NOT start
ORDER BY CREATED_TIME
```